# PySpark doesn't find Kafka source

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to deploy a docker container with Kafka and Spark and would like to read to Kafka Topic from a pyspark application. Kafka is working and I can write to a topic and also spark is working. But when I try to read the Kafka stream I get the error message:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:  Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".
```

My Docker Compose yaml looks like this:

```
---
version: '3.7'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "yes"
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:2
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: >-
          INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: >-
          INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: >-
          INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3-debian-10
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/workspace/
      - ./spark/jars:/opt/bitnami/spark/.ivy2 

  spark-worker-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3-debian-10
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/workspace/
      - ./spark/jars:/opt/bitnami/spark/.ivy2 
      
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

and the pyspark app:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

#os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.1'
# the source for this data pipeline is a kafka topic, defined below
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("fuel-level").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')

kafkaRawStreamingDF = spark                          \
    .readStream                                          \
    .format("kafka")                                     \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe","SimLab-KUKA")                  \
    .option("startingOffsets","earliest")\
    .load()                                     

#this is necessary for Kafka Data Frame to be readable, into a single column  value
kafkaStreamingDF = kafkaRawStreamingDF.selectExpr("cast(key as string) key", "cast(value as string) value")

kafkaStreamingDF.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

I am new to Spark and docker, so maybe It's an obvious mistake, I hope you can help me

EDIT
When I uncomment os.env I get the following error:

```
Error: Missing application resource.

Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]

Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn,
                              k8s://https://host:port, or local (Default: local[*]).
  --deploy-mode DEPLOY_MODE   Whether to launch the driver program locally ("client") or
                              on one of the worker machines inside the cluster ("cluster")
                              (Default: client).
  --class CLASS_NAME          Your application's main class (for Java / Scala apps).
  --name NAME                 A name of your application.
  --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
  --packages                  Comma-separated list of maven coordinates of jars to include
                              on the driver and executor classpaths. Will search the local
                              maven repo, then maven central and any additional remote
                              repositories given by --repositories. The format for the
                              coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.
  --exclude-packages          Comma-separated list of groupId:artifactId, to exclude while
                              resolving the dependencies provided in --packages to avoid
                              dependency conflicts.
  --repositories              Comma-separated list of additional remote repositories to
                              search for the maven coordinates given with --packages.
  --py-files PY_FILES         Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place
                              on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps.
  --files FILES               Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working
                              directory of each executor. File paths of these files
                              in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).
  --archives ARCHIVES         Comma-separated list of archives to be extracted into the
                              working directory of each executor.

  --conf, -c PROP=VALUE       Arbitrary Spark configuration property.
  --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties. If not
                              specified, this will look for conf/spark-defaults.conf.

  --driver-memory MEM         Memory for driver (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1024M).
  --driver-java-options       Extra Java options to pass to the driver.
  --driver-library-path       Extra library path entries to pass to the driver.
  --driver-class-path         Extra class path entries to pass to the driver. Note that
                              jars added with --jars are automatically included in the
                              classpath.

  --executor-memory MEM       Memory per executor (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G).

  --proxy-user NAME           User to impersonate when submitting the application.
                              This argument does not work with --principal / --keytab.

  --help, -h                  Show this help message and exit.
  --verbose, -v               Print additional debug output.
  --version,                  Print the version of current Spark.

 Cluster deploy mode only:
  --driver-cores NUM          Number of cores used by the driver, only in cluster mode
                              (Default: 1).

 Spark standalone or Mesos with cluster deploy mode only:
  --supervise                 If given, restarts the driver on failure.

 Spark standalone, Mesos or K8s with cluster deploy mode only:
  --kill SUBMISSION_ID        If given, kills the driver specified.
  --status SUBMISSION_ID      If given, requests the status of the driver specified.

 Spark standalone, Mesos and Kubernetes only:
  --total-executor-cores NUM  Total cores for all executors.

 Spark standalone, YARN and Kubernetes only:
  --executor-cores NUM        Number of cores used by each executor. (Default: 1 in
                              YARN and K8S modes, or all available cores on the worker
                              in standalone mode).

 Spark on YARN and Kubernetes only:
  --num-executors NUM         Number of executors to launch (Default: 2).
                              If dynamic allocation is enabled, the initial number of
                              executors will be at least NUM.
  --principal PRINCIPAL       Principal to be used to login to KDC.
  --keytab KEYTAB             The full path to the file that contains the keytab for the
                              principal specified above.

 Spark on YARN only:
  --queue QUEUE_NAME          The YARN queue to submit to (Default: "default").
      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/janikbischoff/Documents/Uni/PuL/BA/Code/Tests/spark-test.py", line 6, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("fuel-level").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/janikbischoff/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/janikbischoff/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/janikbischoff/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 144, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/Users/janikbischoff/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 339, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/janikbischoff/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: Did you yry uncommenting `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']`? Note: kafka container is not reachable on `localhost`. You've defined it as `kafka:29092`

Comment: I tried Kafka:29092 but it still doesn't find Kafka. And when I uncomment os.environ I get another Error: Error: Missing application resource.

Comment: That line definitely needs uncommented. Please edit your question to include the full new error

Comment: I added the error

Comment: How are you actually running the code? The error suggests you're running `spark-submit` without your Python file. Also, unrelated to that error, but the master should be `spark://spark:7077` rather than `local[*]`, assuming you're trying to run the code from the master or worker container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Missing application resource

This implies you're running the code using `python` rather than `spark-submit`

I was able to reproduce the error by copying your environment, as well as [using `findspark`](https://github.com/minrk/findspark), it seems `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` aren't working in that container, even though the variable does get loaded...

The workaround would be to pass the argument at execution time.

```
spark-submit \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 \
  script.py
```